# How to make DragDrop.DoDragDrop async?

Tags: c#, wpf, asynchronous, drag-and-drop, clipboard

I use `DragDrop.DoDragDrop` to copy files from my C# WPF application to Windows explorer. However, the actual copying of the files causes my WPF application to freeze until the copying is complete. This copy operation could last a few seconds to several minutes.

```
DataObject dragdata = new DataObject(DataFormats.FileDrop);
System.Collections.Specialized.StringCollection sc = new System.Collections.Specialized.StringCollection();

//fill the StringCollection with filenames

dragdata.SetFileDropList(sc);
DragDrop.DoDragDrop(listviewitem, dragdata, DragDropEffects.Copy);
```

How can I call the DoDragDrop method without freezing/locking my application? I have not been able to make sense of the reported 'async' implementation of DataObject.

Comment: Where does your application freeze? Do you release the mouse? Please provide a repo of your issue when asking a question if you want someone be able to help you: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score -2):

Instead of trying to make the 'DoDragDrop' method perform asynchronously, it is better to perform the copying of file on a different thread instead, as this will allow your main thread, which is running the WPF application's UI, to continue to run (No freezing) while another thread is performing the heavy I/O operation of copying the file. Once the other thread completed, you can notify your main thread that it has finished to display a status message to say that file copying has completed.

Comment: The heavy work of copying the files is handled by Windows Explorer, so it is beyond my control.

Comment: But you would have written code for the actions to happen when you 'Drop' the dragged file, like in this case, I believe you write the codes to call the file copying action.

`private void StackPanel_Drop(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
 {
       // Your codes before you call the method to copy of files.

       // The method for copying files.
       File.Copy(some parameters);
 }`